# css for html attribute

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In my site I have this code (Wordpress / Woocommerce Cart page):

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart">
```

I want to add an update icon after the text "Update Cart" On other pages was it fairly simple using a `:after` pseudo element.

I don't know what I'm missing but I can't get it to work with the mark-up above.
For instance I have tried

```
input[name="update_cart"]::after {
    etc.
 }
```

and

```
.button[name="update_cart"]::after {
    etc.
 }
```

This did not work.
Please advice.

Comment: input type dont support pseudo element add parent and give pseudo classes for that

Comment: OK, that's why.... thanks for the comment. I will try to follow your suggestion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the following note in [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content): “Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.” This has not happened so far, and browsers simply don’t implement those pseudo-elements at all for elements like `input`. But they do implement them for `button`.

So if you can change the markup, you can append generated content to the button text:

```html
<style>
.button[name="update_cart"]:after {
    content: " ⤾";
 }
</style>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart">
<p>
<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart">Update Cart</button>
```

The example includes an `input type=button` element too, to illustrate how the button rendering is the same, except that for `button`, generated content works.

Comment: It did not work as I hoped. The value is added by woocommerce multilingual. What I get is only the icon. The exact code in wordpress is now: `<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php _e( 'Update Cart', 'woocommerce' );?>" />` Sorry for being unclear in my question. Any suggestions?

Comment: Found it! Changed the code to `<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart"/> <?php print _e( 'Update Cart', 'woocommerce' );?> Answer accepted
`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `:after` or `:before` on input or button element.

You can use a span element with a button inside and an `:after` in the span with icon (probably with a character as content using **Font Awsome** or **Icon Moon**).

Don't forget the content inside `:after` css, the pseudo element will not be visible if this css property isn't properly set.